# Set max string length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want my dataframe to auto-truncate strings which are longer than a certain length.

basically:

```
pd.set_option('auto_truncate_string_exceeding_this_length', 255)
```

Any ideas?  I have hundreds of columns and don't want to iterate over every data point.  If this can be achieved during import that would also be fine (e.g. pd.read_csv())

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [read_csv converters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Lets say you want to truncate column name `abc`, you can pass a dictionary with function like

```
def auto_truncate(val):
    return val[:255]
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'abc': auto_truncate}
```

If you have columns with different lengths

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'abc': lambda: x: x[:255], 'xyz': lambda: x: x[:512]}
```

Make sure column type is string. Column index can also be used instead of name in converters dict.

Answer (score 11):

`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 255)`

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want to truncate what is displayed. This answer is not relevant in this sense.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question but does answers a useful one (first google link when searching "increase str length displayed dataframe")

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure you can do this on the whole df, the following would work after loading:

```
In [21]:

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":['jasjdhadasd']*5, "b":arange(5)})
df
Out[21]:
             a  b
0  jasjdhadasd  0
1  jasjdhadasd  1
2  jasjdhadasd  2
3  jasjdhadasd  3
4  jasjdhadasd  4
In [22]:

for col in df:
    if is_string_like(df[col]):
        df[col] = df[col].str.slice(0,5)
df
Out[22]:
       a  b
0  jasjd  0
1  jasjd  1
2  jasjd  2
3  jasjd  3
4  jasjd  4
```

**EDIT**

I think if you specified the dtypes in the args to `read_csv` then you could set the max length:

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=(np.str, maxlen))`

I will try this and confirm shortly

**UPDATE**

Sadly you cannot specify the length, an error is raised if you try this:

```
NotImplementedError: the dtype <U5 is not supported for parsing
```

when attempting to pass the arg `dtype=(str,5)`

Comment: Could be premature to say, but seems like the dtype=(np.str, maxlen) is working for well for me.

Comment: how are you applying this? at `read_csv` or just `df.col.dtype = (np.str, maxlen)`?

Comment: during read_csv. Through 20M records without issue.  If this continues to work then looks like the New Year will come after all.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply truncate a single column with

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str[:255]
```