# Limit dataframe character length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an old Fortran program that reads in .dat files. I am using python to process some text files so that they meet the strict input style of the Fortran program.

I first import the text file an turn it into a dataframe. Now I need to limit the number of characters each column can hold. For example, nine characters in the first column, 5 in the second and so on and so on.
Furthermore, in the instance that one row of the dataframe has less characters than the column limit, I need to fill it out so that it meets the limit. For example, a column has a limit of 5 characters, but row n contains a value of 15, the new value will need to be xxx15

Is what I want to do possible? Can anyone help?
Thanks :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722658/set-max-string-length-in-panda

Comment: it seems pandas option are global across all df and columns.

Comment: Also for padding you could use a function such as `def add_characters(x, size):
    pad = size - len(x)
    
    if pad > 0:
        return "x" * pad + str(x)
    else:
        return x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, so first write a function that will take a string and edit it meet your column length requirement

```
def char_len(x, fixed_n):
    '''set string x to fixed_n character, prepend with 'xxx' if short'''
    if len(x) > fixed_n: 
        return x[:fixed_n] 
    elif len(x) < fixed_n: 
        return 'x' * (fixed_n - len(x)) + x 
    return x
```

then you'll apply the function to each column of the dataframe, passing in the required character length as the second argument to our char_len function

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a', 'abcdef'], 
    'b':['abcdefg', 'hi']})
test_df['a'] = test_df['a'].apply(lambda x: char_len(x, 5))  
test_df['b'] = test_df['b'].apply(lambda x: char_len(x, 4)) 
test_df
```

This assumes that your columns are all strings. If not just coerce them using `.astype(str)`

Comment: Wow! thats awesome! thanks so much for your help. You've saved me hours :D