# Can't pre-define dtype when reading data

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a pipe delimited file without headings into Pandas and I am using Pandas version 0.24.2. And this is public data so no worries around confidentiality.

The data looks like:

```
999778247820|R|JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION|7.375|113000|360|02/2001|04/2001|95|95|1|52|665|Y|P|SF|1|P|IL|601|30|FRM||1|N
999783196683|R|OTHER|7.25|59000|360|01/2001|04/2001|97|97|2|43|682|Y|P|PU|1|P|HI|967|30|FRM|676|1|N
999783470376|C|BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.|7.875|110000|360|12/2000|02/2001|74|74|2|26|700|N|P|SF|1|P|NY|125||FRM|698||N
999786911479|C|BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.|7.5|57000|360|12/2000|02/2001|90|90|1|28|699|N|P|SF|1|P|TX|781|25|FRM||1|N
999786913710|R|JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA|7.125|114000|360|01/2001|04/2001|73|73|2|16|745|N|C|SF|1|P|WA|992||FRM|||N
999788833695|B|OTHER|9|50000|360|10/2000|12/2000|90|90|2|40|674|N|P|SF|2|I|WI|535|25|FRM|737|1|N
```

This is the code I am using:

```py
orig_files_fnma = glob.glob("/...1/Acquisition*.txt")

col_names = ["loan_id", "origination_channel","seller_name","original_interest_rate","original_upb","original_loan_term","origination_date","first_payment_date","original_ltv","original_cltv","number_of_borrowers","original_dti",
            "borrower_fico_at_origination","first_time_home_buyer_indicator", "loan_purpose","property_type","number_of_units","occupancy_type","property_state","zip_code_short","primary_mortgage_insurance_percent",
            "product_type","coborrower_fico_at_origination","mortgage_insurance_type","relocation_mortgage_indicator"]

col_type = {"loan_id": "object","origination_channel": "object","seller_name": "object","original_interest_rate": "float","original_upb": "float","original_loan_term": "int","origination_date": "object",
            "first_payment_date": "object","original_ltv": "object","original_cltv": "object","number_of_borrowers": "int","original_dti": "float","borrower_fico_at_origination": "int",
            "first_time_home_buyer_indicator": "object", "loan_purpose": "object","property_type": "object","number_of_units": "int","occupancy_type": "object","property_state": "object",
            "zip_code_short": "object","primary_mortgage_insurance_percent": "float",
            "product_type": "object","coborrower_fico_at_origination": "int","mortgage_insurance_type": "object","relocation_mortgage_indicator": "object"}

dfs = []
temp_df = []

for orig_files_fnma in orig_files_fnma:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(orig_files_fnma, sep = '|', header = None, names = col_names, dtype = col_type, index_col = None, parse_dates=True, verbose = True, engine='python')
    dfs.append(temp_df)
```

Always getting the following errors:

```py
Filled 1 NA values in column original_ltv
Filled 52 NA values in column original_cltv
ValueError: Unable to convert column number_of_borrowers to type int
```

I do find out if I don't pre-define the dtype and .astype to change the data type after loading. But ask if possible that I can pre-define the data type first like the code above.

Also, I want to define the length of object for 20 length. What is the right code to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a different error:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert column coborrower_fico_at_origination to type int
```

import you import the data into Excel, you will see that there are 3 rows in this columns that are blank. The `int` type cannot handle blanks. You should change it to float, upon which blanks become `nan`:

```
col_type = {..., "coborrower_fico_at_origination": "float", ...}
```

The command succeeded after that.

Comment: When changing all int type to float type, it works. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, do you know whether it matters for object type field for different lengths. For exampe, I want the loan_id field to be 20 digit length.

Comment: pandas does not impose a length limit for the string columns like most RDBMS do. If you want to set a limit upon parsing the files, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722658/set-max-string-length-in-pandas