# How to remove the skipped blank lines using savetxt in python

Tags: python

I have the following code.

```
Import numpy as np
np.savetxt(file_output_path, df.values, fmt='%s',delimiter='')
```

it's supposed to write data to fixed width length from dataframe. The output is fixed-width-length. However, I noticed the output has skipped lines for every single rows as example below

```
Jonh   Nguyen   25

Steven Wood     35

Kevin  Wu       45
```

How can I remove the skipped lines as result below?

```
 Jonh   Nguyen   25
 Steven Wood     35
 Kevin  Wu       45
```

Comment: Could you please show also your original data frame in order to highlight that it does not contain the newlines at the end of last columns?

Comment: the dataframe came from SQL server df_1 = pd.read_sql_query(_SQL1, conn)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, to save data in CSV format.

```
df.to_csv(r'export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Else, to save in txt format:

```
df.to_csv(r'export_dataframe.txt', index = False, header=False)
```

More info:
Signature:

```
df.to_csv(
    path_or_buf=None,
    sep=',',
    na_rep='',
    float_format=None,
    columns=None,
    header=True,
    index=True,
    index_label=None,
    mode='w',
    encoding=None,
    compression='infer',
    quoting=None,
    quotechar='"',
    line_terminator=None,
    chunksize=None,
    tupleize_cols=None,
    date_format=None,
    doublequote=True,
    escapechar=None,
    decimal='.',
)
```

Comment: how can i specify the fixed width if i use df.to_csv

Comment: fixed width for what? can you give an example?

Comment: df_csv is only export the data frame as pipe or a character as separated column. it does not set a fixed width of the column based on the business rules for example Last  Name= 12 characters, First Name = 10 characters and age = 3 charaters.

Comment: In that case, you can limit the strings by using maxlen in that DataFrame itself. Check this for more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722658/set-max-string-length-in-pandas

Comment: if you have 100 columns you have to specify 100 times for each columns for specify the length of each columns?

Comment: Please do read the previous comments. You just need to specify once for all columns.